# Remove (not close) my Outlook data files

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I installed MS Office including Outlook.  I botched the job and would like to start over.

Before I uninstall and then re-install Outlook I would like to remove, not close all existing data files.

Losing the data and all existing Outlook files is the desired result.

Comment: By "data files" if you mean .PSTs, close (completely exit) Outlook, uninstall it and just delete anything that's left (check for stray files in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook).

Comment: Karan, why is this not an answer?

Comment: @DaveRook: It sounded so obvious that I thought perhaps there's something more to it, and the OP might clarify. :) (BTW, I saw your comment just now because I happened to re-open this topic. Don't forget the @ if you want to notify someone!)

Answer (score 0):

Close the files within Outlook, then close Outlook. Then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> the files (bypassing bin).

Comment: Which "files" are you talking about?

Comment: All files relating to previously installed outlook accounts, so that I can correctly install my email accounts.